# How to create a popup of checkboxes on clicking an item in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that displays only images. I want a functionality where if I click on any image in the ListView, it should open a popup menu and the popup menu should contain 3-4 check boxes with some names representing the folders that the user would want to put that image into.

I searched everywhere but, couldn't find any such tutorials. How should I go about implementing that?

Comment: you have to make a custom dialog and then you can put a listview or gridview and shows the folder on it.

Comment: @arjunkn List/GridView is not necessary. Android SDK provides an easy way. Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
final CharSequence[] items = {" Easy "," Medium "," Hard "," Very Hard "};
final ArrayList selectedItems=new ArrayList();
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActualActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("This is a title");

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            //Here you add or remove the items from the list selectedItems. That list will be the result of the user selection.
            if (isChecked) {
                selectedItems.add(which);
             } else if (selectedItems.contains(which)) {
                        selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }
                }
            });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //Do something when the user closes the dialog by pressing the Done button
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             dialog.dismiss();
             //Do something else if you want
        }
    });

       builder.create();
       builder.show();
    }
});
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954352/2823516)!